# EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'

Tags: sql-server, deployment, clr

I've built a CLR dll and I deployed it to DEV and TEST Sql server instances without problems.
My CLR is Signed with an asymmetric key that is associated to a CLRLogin.
I did it in all my 3 environment Sql Instances: DEV, TEST and PRODuction.

The problem is that, when I deploy my CLR to PROD environment I receive the following error:

```
EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'
```

I don't want to set my database as Trutworthy ON because I didn't do that in my DEV and TEST SqlServer databases where CLR was deployed correctly.

In addition, the same Asymmetric Key and the same CLRLogin is used on PROD machine for another CLR dll with EXTERNAL ACCESS deployed on another database.

Can someone help me understanding the problem?
Is ther something that I've to do on my PROD database?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: grant EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY to the certificate login on prod  `grant EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY to certloginnamegoeshere`

Comment: I already "re-executed" following command:

"use master;
grant external access assembly to CLRLogin;" but with no success...same problem

Comment: But the same Asymmetric Key and the same CLRLogin is used on PROD machine for another CLR dll with EXTERNAL ACCESS deployed on another database that works correctly. I think there's something to do on my DB. But can the same CLRLogin execute different DLLs on different DB?

Comment: revoke and grant again? (revoke EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY to CLRLogin;grantEXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY to CLRLogin;) also try to create (or remap) a dbuser for CLRLogin: use dbnamegoeshere; create user clrloginuser for login CLRLogin;

Comment: Ok I solved my problem. I tried to deploy, on PROD SqlServer, my CLR from visual studio using a user with limited premissions. In DEV and TEST the user I used was sys admin. Now for deploy I used a login that was sys admin and it worked. Do you know which specific permissions needs a user to deploy a CLR?  @lptr...thanks very much for your help attempts :)

Comment: Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can create and alter UNSAFE assemblies.  Requires CREATE ASSEMBLY permission.
If PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS is specified, requires EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY permission on the server. If PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE is specified, requires UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission on the server. ... and a few more... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions